# Вставить html для каждого элемента массива

Tags: javascript

есть разметка:

```
<div id="time-part" class="reserv__dates">

</div>
```

и есть JS , его приведу ниже.

Я получаю на входе коллекцию html элементов, с определенным css классом.
Каждый из этих элементов имеет информацию в data атрибутах.
Моя задача взять из каждого элемента информацию из этих data атрибутов и вставить их в блок html приведенный выше.
В data атрибутах есть день и месяц, который мне нужно вывести в одинаковый блок html.

Мой код делает то что мне нужно, но выводит только один блок. Те если мне приходит коллеция с одним блоком, все работает, если с 2 и более , то он видимо выводит информацию из каждого, но заменяет ее каждым следующим, и в моем html остается только информация из последнего блока.

вот код:

```
const timePartBlock = document.getElementById('time-part');

nextButton1.addEventListener('click', function(event){

    let allActiveDays = document.getElementsByClassName('month__date-active');

    if (allActiveDays.length == 0 ) {
        alert('Выберите интересующую дату');
    } else {

        for (i = 0; i < allActiveDays.length; i++) {
                let dateDay = allActiveDays[i].dataset.day;
                let dateMonth = allActiveDays[i].dataset.month;

                timePartBlock.innerHTML = '<div class="reserv__date" >' + dateDay + ' ' + dateMonth + '</div>'; 

            }         
        }; 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

в итоге верное решение:

```
const timePartBlock = document.getElementById('time-part');

nextButton1.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    let allActiveDays = document.getElementsByClassName('month__date-active');
    let data;


    if (allActiveDays.length == 0 ) {
        alert('Выберите интересующую дату');
    } else {

        for (i = 0; i < allActiveDays.length; i++) {
                let dateDay = allActiveDays[i].dataset.day;
                let dateMonth = allActiveDays[i].dataset.month;
                data += '<div class="reserv__date" >' + dateDay + ' ' + dateMonth + '</div>'; 

            }

           timePartBlock.innerHTML = data;

        };



})
```

добавил новую переменную, и в нее записывал результат